# change current TextArea value without assign a new one?

Tags: javascript, html

When I press "A" to add a character to a value of the TextArea, how does the value change?
does the browser do something like this:

```
texarea.value+="A";
//same as:
texarea.value=texarea.value+"A";
```

?

I would like to change that value dynamicaly and notify the textarea about the change without assign a new one, because I think that assingment is not very perfomant if the value takes a lot of memory.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Strings are immutable.  That is the only way to do it.

Comment: It would be cool, when you could extend a TextArea and overreide some of its methods to represent its value not as a String rather as a list of chars or array of chars, and add some methods to notify the textarea about the changes made on this list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved it:

at first sight this solution seems also not very performant, but it has some big advatages:
for example you could load only a specific part of a very big file from server and dynamically load it if the user scroll through the page.
you can also update the client version of the file representation (synchronized editing)

```js
document.registerElement('text-area', class NicePanel extends HTMLElement {
  createdCallback() {
    //this.root = this.createShadowRoot();
    this.tabIndex = 1;
    this.onkeydown = function(e) {
      this.monkeydown(e);
    }
    this.onkeypress = function(e) {
      this.monkeypress(e);
    }

    this.setValue(this.innerHTML);
  }
  setValue(value) {
    var mutablestring = Array.from(value);
    this.innerHTML = "";
    var l = mutablestring.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
      if (mutablestring[i] == '\n') {
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        br.onclick = this.characterClick;
        this.appendChild(br);
      } else {
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.onclick = this.characterClick;
        span.innerHTML = mutablestring[i];
        this.appendChild(span);
      }
    }
    this.cursor = document.createElement('span');
    this.cursor.innerHTML = "|";
    this.appendChild(this.cursor);
  }
  getValue() {
    var value = "";
    var children = this.childNodes;
    var that = this;
    children.forEach(function(child) {
      if (child.nodeName == "BR") {
        value += "\n";
        return;
      }
      if (child === that.cursor) return;
      value += child.innerHTML;
    });

    return value;
  }

  attachedCallback() {}
  monkeydown(e) {
    var KeyID = event.keyCode;
    switch (KeyID) {
      case 8:
        this.cursor.parentNode.removeChild(this.cursor.previousSibling);

        e.preventDefault();
        break;
      case 46:
        this.cursor.parentNode.removeChild(this.cursor.nextSibling);
        e.preventDefault();
        break;

      case 13:
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        br.onclick = this.characterClick;
        this.cursor.before(br);
        e.preventDefault();
        break;
      case 37: //left
        this.cursor.parentNode.insertBefore(this.cursor, this.cursor.previousSibling);
        break;
      case 38: //up
        break;
      case 39: //right
        this.cursor.parentNode.insertBefore(this.cursor, this.cursor.nextSibling.nextSibling);
        break;
      case 40: //down
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
  characterClick(e) {
    this.parentNode.cursor.parentNode.insertBefore(this.parentNode.cursor, e.target);
  }
  monkeypress(e) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.onclick = this.characterClick;

    span.innerHTML = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
    this.cursor.parentNode.insertBefore(span, this.cursor);
  }
  monclick(e) {
    var target = e.target; // Clicked element
    while (target && target.parentNode !== this) {
      target = target.parentNode; // If the clicked element isn't a direct child
      if (!target) {
        return;
      } // If element doesn't exist
    }
    if (target.tagName === 'SPAN') {
      alert(target.id); // Check if the element is a LI
    }
  }
})
var myta = document.getElementById('myta');
myta.setValue("huhu\nlala");
console.log(myta.getValue());
```

```css
text-area {
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<text-area id="myta" class="text">Hello World

</text-area>
```

Comment: Unnecessarily complicated

Comment: The next step is synchronized editing like by google docs :-) With this concept it is posible